# How to make json ajax call in jsTree

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, jstree

I want to make ajax call to get data for `results` nodes. In my sample code [(see here)](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/G789k/) the ajax call is made but the server doesn't return any thing (tested using firebug) But if I use the same url in a web browser I can save the json file.

My questions are:

- how to make the ajax call to work so the return values are displayed in jsTree? It works nicely [here](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data#) - search for `Using both the data & ajax config options`
- how to pass the ajax call **parameters**

  - one would be the parent/parent name ( **basics** for the first results node )
  - second one would be the parent node's name ( **login** for the first results node)

See my code below or use the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/G789k/)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jsTree & ajax</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/_docs/syntax/!script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        data = [
                    {
                        "data" : "Basics",
                        "state" : "closed",
                                            "children" : [ {
                                                                "data" : "login",
                                                                    "state" : "closed",
                                                                    "children" : [ "login", {"data" : "results", "state" : "closed"} ]
                                                                    }   , 
                {
                "data" : "Basics",
                    "state" : "closed",
                    "children" : [ "login", "something",{"data" : "results", "state" : "closed"} ]
                    }    ]
                    },
                    {
                        "data" : "All",
                        "state" : "closed",
                "children" : [ {
                "data" : "AddCustomer",
                    "state" : "closed",
                    "children" : [ "login","Add", {"data" : "results", "state" : "closed"} ]
                    }   ]
                    }
                ]
$(function () {
        $("#jstree").jstree({
            "json_data" : {
                "data" : data ,
                "ajax" : { "url" : "http://www.jstree.com/static/v.1.0pre/_docs/_json_data.json" }
            },
            "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data" ]
        });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="jstree"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Update 1

Even I copy the sample code from jstree.com into [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/G789k/1/) it won't work. I guess I am missing something somewhere....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try not to make Ajax calls from your server to another server - this will result in a cross-domain security exception. There are ways around it (JSONP) but it is simpler to just request data from your own server.

Once you've sorted out your ajax request, you probably want to add some attributes to your "results" nodes so that the ajax has some data it can hook into, e.g. IDs. Something like:

```
"data": "results", "state": "closed", "attr": { "id": "node-123" }
```

Then you can add a handler for the ajax data option:

```
"ajax": {
    "url": "/my/local/json/",
    "data": function(n) {
        // get parent / grandparent node
        var lists = $(n).parents('ul');
        var p = $(lists[0]).prev('a');
        var gp = $(lists[1]).prev('a');
        // the result is fed to the AJAX request 'data' option
        return {
            "parent": $.trim(p.text()),
            "grandparent": $.trim(gp.text()),
            "id": n.attr ? n.attr("id").replace("node-", "") : 1,

        };
    }
}
```

This should result in an Ajax request such as: http://myserver/my/local/json/?parent=login&grandparent=Basics&id=123

Hope that helps.

Edit: here's an updated JsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/robgallen/3uCX3/

Comment: Any idea why, when I use `jsTreeGrid` your code doesn't give me parent's and grandparent's name? http://jsfiddle.net/radek/Dax4D/1/

Comment: It's because grid adds some divs between the A tag and the UL tag. Try using .siblings('a') instead of .prev('a') for the two variables p & gp.

Comment: You're right. Everything works as desired. Thank you sooooo much for your help.

Comment: I dont' understand this `"id": n.attr ? n.attr("id").replace("node-", "") : 1,`, could you explain? I thought that you check if attribute exists then modify it otherwise set to 1. But I am not sure about that.

Comment: Yeh that code is basically from the jstree site. It's a turnery key, so could be written instead as if/else statement. It just checks to see whether n.attr exists (as a function/property) before retrieving the id attribute and stripping "node-" from it so it just has the id number. This is what gets sent in the querystring.

Comment: But `console.log(n.attr);` returns text `function()`, nothing like true as I would expect from a condition.

Comment: It's not testing for a boolean, rather it is testing that n.attr is not null or undefined, so as long as it returns something (in this case a function) it passes the condition. Basically it is to make sure that when you call n.attr("id") it doesn't blow up.

Comment: `as long as it returns something` - wow. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: The updated fiddle link is not showing anything in the results.